# Make =IF Function Output Numbers For "Scoring": Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm am exploring methods of giving scores to different datapoints within a dataset. These points come from a mix of numbers and text string attributes looking for certain characteristics, e.g. if Col. A contains more than X number of "|", then give it a 1. If not, it gets a 0 for that category. I also have some that give the point when the value is >X.

I have been trying to do this with =IF, for example, =IF([sheet] = [Text], "1","0").

I can get it to give me 1 or 0, but I am unable to get a point total with sum.

I have tried changing the formatting of the text to both "number", "plain text", and have left it as automatic, but I can't get it to sum. Thoughts? Is there maybe a better way to do this?

FWIW - I'm trying to score based on about 12 factors.

Best,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

The issue here might be that you're having the cell evaluate to either the *string* `"0"` or the *string* `"1"` rather than the *number* 0 or the *number* 1. That would explain why you're seeing the right things but the math isn't coming out right - the cell contents *look* like numbers, but they're really text, which the summation would then ignore.

One option would be to drop the quotation marks and write something like this:

```
=IF(condition, 1, 0)
```

This has the condition evaluate to 1 if it's true and 0 if it's false.

Alternatively, you could write something like this:

```
=(condition) * 1
```

This will take the boolean TRUE or FALSE returned by `condition` and convert it to either the numeric value 1 (true) or the numeric value 0 (false).

Comment: That did it. I knew it had to be an easy fix like that. Thank you for your help.